# Identify duplicate grouped columns of data within the same row R

Tags: r, function, duplicates

First - I looked through other questions and answers, I did not find one that uniquely addresses this. If I'm wrong, please point me to the answer.

I have data as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(key=c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'),
      name1=c('black','black','black','red','red'),
      type1=c('chair','chair','sofa','sofa','plate'),
      num1=c(4,5,12,4,3),
      name2=c('black', 'red', 'black', 'green', 'blue'),
      type2=c('chair','chair','sofa','bed','plate'),
      num2=c(4,7,12,3,1),
      name3=c('blue', 'green', 'black', 'blue', 'blue'),
      type3=c('couch','chair','sofa','plate','plate'),
      num3=c(12,8,12,4,1))

key | name1 | type1 | num1 | name2 | type2 | num2 | name3 | type3 | num3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     black   chair    4     black   chair   4      blue    couch   12
2     black   chair    5     red     chair   7      green   chair   8
3     black   sofa     12    black   sofa    12     black   sofa    12
4     red     sofa     4     green   bed     3      purple  bowl    4
5     red     plate    3     blue    plate   1      blue    plate   1
```

For one primary key, there are groups of data, all on the same row.

I need to:

- Identify duplicate groups of data per row, if there are any
- Count number of duplicates per row
- Create one column that is a simple dummy (are there dupes in row 1/0)
- Create columns that are the values of any duplicates

So with the data above, I'd like to add on the right side

```
key | dupes | N_d_1 | name_d_1 | type_d_1 | num_d_1 | ...N_d_X
 1     1       2       black      chair      4
 2     0       0         NA         NA       NA
 3     1       3       black      sofa       12
 4     0       0         NA         NA       NA
 5     1       2       blue       plate      1
```

Complications -

There are close to 100 groups of 9 columns each, and there will be multiple groups of duplicates. I need to see those values, all of them, and the sum of dupes needs to account for these different groups of duplicates.

I could do this with a gargantuan series of IF name_d_1==name_d_X & type etc, but I assume there is a shorter faster way to do that, which I am not aware of. The output should probably be a separate dataframe that has each key but only pulls and produced variables for duplicates...there are already far too many columns for R to deal with effectively.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

group_len <- 3
groups <- split(2:ncol(df), cut(2:ncol(df), 3))

stacked.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(groups, function(cols) {
    group <- df[ , c(1, cols)]  
    names(group) <- c("key", "name", "type", "num")
    group
}))

group_by(stacked.df, key, name, type, num) %>% 
    summarise(dupes = n() > 1, num_dupes = n())
```

This gives the data you want but in long form:

```
    # A tibble: 11 x 6
# Groups:   key, name, type [?]
   key   name  type    num dupes num_dupes
   <fct> <fct> <fct> <dbl> <lgl>     <int>
 1 1     black chair  4.00 T             2
 2 1     blue  couch 12.0  F             1
 3 2     black chair  5.00 F             1
 4 2     red   chair  7.00 F             1
 5 2     green chair  8.00 F             1
 6 3     black sofa  12.0  T             3
 7 4     red   sofa   4.00 F             1
 8 4     blue  plate  4.00 F             1
 9 4     green bed    3.00 F             1
10 5     red   plate  3.00 F             1
11 5     blue  plate  1.00 T             2
```

To get it into wide form as you requested, I'd suggest looking into `tidyr`'s `spread` function or `data.table`'s `dcast` function.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is a great first step.